# Unable to load website on a corporate wi-fi network that uses captive portal authentication

Tags: php, session, cookies

We have a site coded in PHP that gets an Unable to Connect error on some corporate wi-fi networks and nowhere else. In some cases, a few pages will load properly before getting Unable to Connect. The entire site uses SSL encryption and uses cookies to manage sessions. We're thinking that there may be some additional protections in the corporate firewalls. Has anyone else seen this before?

Thanks!